# Prove the equation using a combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Prove using a **combinatorial** argument that both sides count the same thing:

$${{n \choose 2} + 1 \choose 2} = {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 4} + 3{n \choose 3}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim.** Both sides represent the number of ways to choose one or two edges from a complete graph on *n* vertices.

*Proof.* The left hand side is obvious, while the three summands on the right hand side are respectively equal to the number of ways in which the chosen edges are incident to precisely 2,4,3 vertices.